# Word for a salesperson's enthusiasm

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english, vocabulary, sentence

Suppose you visit a shop looking for something to buy. Every time 
you pick up an object, the shopkeeper goes gaga over the features of the product
and why it's a must-buy.

I'm searching for a single word which describes the enthusiasm and/or marketing effort of the shopkeeper.
I'm not sure, but *pushy* may be one possibility.

For instance:

> The shopkeeper sounded too pushy

However, I'm not sure. 
Does anyone have a better or more correct choice of word?

Comment: "Every time you pick up a thing" vs "Every time you pick up an item"

Comment: Maybe "hard sell" ... "he gave us the hard-sell every time we touched something!"  "Pushy" is good, if that's what you mean.  "Effusive" is a similar word, more like "talkative."

Comment: @JoeBlow But how would i re phrase my sentence using hard sell. I want to keep sentence like `the shopkeeper sounded too __________ `

Comment: pushy is the best word in that sentence. or "The shopkeeper kept giving us the hard-sell."

Comment: If you want to give a sense of what the shopkeeper is overdoing in his or her approach to the potential sale, try _enthusiastic_, as in "The shopkeeper acted too enthusiastic." If you're looking for a word with a slightly creepy edge, consider _hungry_, as in "The shopkeeper seemed too hungry."

Answer (score 2):

I think you are referring to:

*[Hard sell](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/h/hard-sell.asp)* practices:

> - high-pressure selling techniques. (*Typically: get ~ give someone ~.) They gave me the [hard sell](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/the+hard+sell), but I still wouldn't buy the car. The clerk gave the customer the hard sell.
> - Advertising and sales practices denoted by aggressive or forceful language. A hard sell is designed to get a consumer to purchase a good or service in the short-term, rather than evaluate his or her options and potentially decide to wait on the purchase. It is considered a high-pressure technique.

- High Street fashion stores are now using U.S.-style, hard-sell tactics. We investigate the tricks of the trade and show you how to avoid them.

Source: http://www.dailymail.co.uk/femail/article-1285411/Why-shop-assistant-says-look

Comment: But how would i re phrase my sentence using `hard sell`. I want to keep sentence like `the shopkeeper sounded too __________` ....

Comment: @iJay I think your original idea of 'pushy' fits perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider "***effusive***", or "***gushing***":

> [***effusive***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/effusive?showCookiePolicy=true) (adj):  extravagantly demonstrative of emotion; gushing
>
> [***gushing***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/gushing?showCookiePolicy=true):  (v) to act or utter in an overeffusive, affected, or sentimental manner.
>
> (n) an extravagant and insincere expression of admiration, sentiment, etc

Or, particularly in a situation where you're clothes shopping and the sales clerk tells you "you look amazing in that!" no matter what you put on or how it looks on you, and in general is overdoing it with the attention and flattery, you could say he is "***fawning***", "***obsequious***", "***unctuous***" (my personal favorite, it just *sounds* slimy), or any number of synonyms.

> [***unctuous***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/unctuous?showCookiePolicy=true):  (of a person) excessively or ingratiatingly flattering; oily. Affecting an oily charm.

Finally, there are a set of *over-* words which emphasize different aspects of this annoying behavior:

> [***overeager***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/overeager?showCookiePolicy=true): excessively eager or keen
>
> [***overbearing***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/overbearing?showCookiePolicy=true): domineering manner or action; bossy, pushy
>
> [***overweening***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/overweening?showCookiePolicy=true): (of a person) excessively arrogant or presumptuous

---

**EDIT**: Ok, I just went back and read the comments. Are you simply looking for

> *The sales person was way too **insistent***

?

Answer (score 1):

Consider *[ebullient](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ebullient)*

> overflowing with enthusiasm or excitement; exuberant [*Collins*]

While not inherently negative, there is an *over the top* connotation in the term, especially if paired with *too*.

Also consider *[irrepressible](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/irrepressible)*

> lively, confident, and impossible to control [*Macmillan*]

Similarly, it is not necessarily negative, but give the suggestion of *out of control*.

Answer (score 0):

How about **eager**: `(of a person) wanting to do or have something very much.`